# Java RegExp: Finding the correct regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling with finding the correct regular expression for extracting the strings according to the following criteria:

I have an xml fragment with multiple tags. Each element starts with `<ABC_xxxx>` and ends with `</ABC_xxxx>`

The xxxx changes for each element. For example:

```
 <ABC_A1S1>1234</ABC_A1S1>
 <ABC_uw3ey>1234</ABC_uw3ey>
 <ABC_PD4frfr5>1234</ABC_PD4frfr5>
```

etc...

The number of x is not fixed!

I want to extract each element, including the tags themselves.

How can I do that?

Comment: Also - [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2071828). Don't do it. Use XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there will be no such elements nested inside each other, try this:

```
\<ABC(\w+)\>[^\<]+\<\/ABC(\1)\>
```

Explanation:

- `\<ABC(\w+)\>` is the opening tag that starts with `ABC` the letters after `ABC` are captured in a group (hence parentheses). We need them later
- `[^\<]+` is the body of the element which is any character except opening angle bracket
- `<\/ABC(\1)\>` is the closing element that starts with `ABC` and must follow with the exact letters after `ABC` in the opening tag. `\1` is a reference to the first captured group.

**Important Note**: XML is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), therefore Regular Expressions are not capable to parse it. E.g., imagine 2 or more such elements nested inside each other. Use an XML parser to parse XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ABC_([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/ABC_([^>]*)>
```